# Fake Page Turn Animation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to create a page turn animation in an Android app, however its in the context of a webview. The webview is a container for the Readium SDK.

Jquery is also included in the page.

The structure of the HTML is like this:

```
<div id="viewport_fixed">
    <div id="spread-wrap" class="clearfix">
      <div class="fixed-page-wrap right_page">
        <iframe class="fixed_iframe" src="blah"></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="fixed-page-wrap left_page">
        <iframe class="fixed_iframe" src="blah"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have looked at several jQuery page turn plugins and tutorials but they 
all assume you have all the pages loaded in a list of DIVs.

While I have two divs its the iFrames that get reloaded when Readium does a
page turn. So I want to fake a page turn animation, not actually bringing in
new content as it happens, but I just can't think of a reasonable approach 
that will let me do that.

Has anyone a good idea of where to start?

Comment: Take a screenshot using Canvas, hide the content, then manipulate that layer alone.

Comment: Thats not a bad idea, I'll have a look into it.

Comment: You also might try having all your iframe divs display:none except for the current one.  You could do some kind of opaque overlay on the page animation to turn while you hide the current and then expose the next/previous.